# Is there a way to create a listbox in Tkinter where each element includes a paragraph?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm in the middle of creating a program that uses Tkinter and praw to delete Reddit posts/comments. I've created a simplistic script in python for deleting posts/comments before, but I was looking to create something with a few more options. The inspiration for this was Shreddit.

The program I've written allows for selecting comments/posts by vote count, black/white listed subreddit, and post date. I'm looking to add an option so that items can be choosen with a fine-tooth comb, by selecting comments/posts by their title and text.

I was thinking of adding a Listbox that includes subreddit/title/votes/content. Form this would take is shown below:

Subreddit - Post Title - Votes - Content type

ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent

Likely limited to three lines of content. The variable of each element will be its id so that the selected elements can be looped through and deleted.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Listbox cannot have columns, it just have one column. Try treeview.

Comment: @Cool. Thanks for the suggestion. I considered using tree view and I’m still open to the idea, but I don’t necessarily need the data in separate columns. All of the labels as well as the content can be part of one string. I’m more concerned with being able to display multiple lines for each entry in the Listbox or Treeview if that’s what I ultimately end up using.

Comment: You could display multiple lines with \n I believe

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @CoolCloud, I tried using this last night, but it didn't work. I ended up finding out that using this method isn't viable. I found what might be a possible solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42842866/17187892