# How can I display information on separate lines in my GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface

I am creating a program that will display the user entered information of a newly packaged beer. As it currently stands, when I click the display button after adding the beer to the beerList, it displays on one line in the display box. I want to change this so that Name, Packaged On, and Bottles display on one line while Cases produced and Bottles display underneath with Batch being by itself on a third line. How can I produce that output?

My GUI's display method:

```
def displayItems(self):
    self.listbox.delete(0, tk.END)
            
    fontToUse = tkinter.font.Font(family = self.font_fam.get(),
                                  weight = 'normal')
    self.listbox.config(font = fontToUse)
            
    for beer in self.__beerList:
        beerString = 'Name: {}\n   Brewed on: {}\n   Packaged on: {}\n   {}\n Cases produced   {}\n Bottles   Batch: {}\n'.format(beer.name, beer.brewDate, beer.pkgDate, beer.numCase, beer.numBtl, beer.batchNum)
        self.listbox.insert(tk.END, beerString)
```

Beer class:

```
    def __str__(self):
        '''string representation for beer object'''
        return f'Beer Name: {self.__name:3}' + \
               f'\nBrew Date: {self.__brewDate:3}' + \
               f'\nPackaging Date: {self.__pkgDate:3}' + \
               f'\nCases: {self.__numCase:3}' + \
               f'\nBottles: {self.__numBtl:3}' + \
               f'\nBatch Number: {self.__batchNum:3}'
```

Comment: Please post the display code here, not a link to a remote site. None of the class implementation except the `__str__()` method is relevant to this question.

Comment: I just posted only my display method and removed my class except for the __str__().

Comment: You may find PySimpleGui easier to deal with than Tkinter: https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Your Beer.__str__() method looks like each item is printed on a separate line, but that's not what you've described... Also, the for loop in displayItems() appears redundant with Beer.__str__().

Comment: You're not even using `str(beer)` in `displayItems`.

Comment: I suspect this is a limitation of the `Listbox` widget. Each item is just a single line.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42683476/how-can-i-make-a-single-tkinter-listbox-element-appear-with-line-breaks